# Api I respond returns Undefined

Tags: node.js, api

I have a problem. I have an Api Url and want that the respond is `console.log`. But when I start my server the respond returns undefined.

```
const express=require("express");
const https=require("https");
const app=express();
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  const location="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Saulheim&appid="My Api Key"&units=metric";

  https.get(location,function(request,respond){

    console.log(respond);
  })
  res.send("Everything is fine");
})





app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
})
```

But the terminal is telling me just: Server is running on port 3000
undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback function of `https.get` only accepts one parameter, which is the response. So your code should be fixed as follows.
Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback

```
pp.get("/",function(req,res){
  const location="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Saulheim&appid="My Api Key"&units=metric";

  https.get(location, function(respond){

    console.log(respond);
  })
  res.send("Everything is fine");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are missing

```
const express = require('express')
```